# QGraphicsOpacityEffect make CPU tired

Tags: qt, qt4

I want my widget Gradually appeared .

```
QGraphicsOpacityEffect *opacityEffect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
myWidget->setGraphicsEffect(opacityEffect);
opacityEffect->setOpacity(0);

QTimer timerOpacity = new QTimer(this);
connect(timerOpacity,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(changeOpacity()));
timerOpacity->start(100);

void Widget::changeOpacity()
{
    float opacity[10] =  {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1};
    this->opacityEffect->setOpacity(opacity[opalevel]);

    if (opalevel >= 9)
    {
        opalevel = 0;
        this->opacityEffect->setOpacity(1);
        this->timerOpacity->stop();
    }

    opalevel++;
}
```

I'm  very satisfied with the effect of debugging on a computer.What I want to emphasize is the fact that when running on ARM11+Linux+Qt-embedded-4.6,the effect was bad.CPU load is too large,and the mouse response is slow .
How to solve this problem ? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am guessing it is because your desktop will OpenGL accelerate the rendering, whilst the ARM processor will have to render it in software.  Without knowing more about the specifications of the ARM processor, I can't be more specific.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QGraphicsOpacityEffect'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to hardware performance is limited, I reset color depth from 32bit to 16bit, the effect is very smooth.